# IOS: How to make a shadow for UIView on 4 side (top,right,bottom and left)

Tags: ios, uiview

I am using the code below to make the shadow for my `ImageView`

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.avatarImageView.bounds];
self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

It will drop a shadow in the right and bottom like this image.

[image]

Now I want to make my `ImageView` also have a shadow in top and left.
What should I change in code?
Is possible to make the view contains shadow in top,right,bottom,left by config in code only or I need to create other layout view for shadow? Any help would be great appreciated.

Here is what I want to achieve
[image]

**Update**
Thank @Dipen Panchasara for give a simple solution. Follow @Dipen Panchasara (with the shadow color is black) I will have the shadow image like this
[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Like this:

```
float shadowSize = 10.0f;
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(self.avatarImageView.frame.origin.x - shadowSize / 2,
                                                                       self.avatarImageView.frame.origin.y - shadowSize / 2,
                                                                       self.avatarImageView.frame.size.width + shadowSize,
                                                                       self.avatarImageView.frame.size.height + shadowSize)];
self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

**Swift 3** version:

```
    let shadowSize : CGFloat = 5.0
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -shadowSize / 2,
                                               y: -shadowSize / 2,
                                               width: self.avatarImageView.frame.size.width + shadowSize,
                                               height: self.avatarImageView.frame.size.height + shadowSize))
    self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
```

Comment: this will give the shadow for 4 side (top : 5, left : 5, bottom: 10, right: 10). work perfect, thank you

Comment: @PhanVanLinh, the first example given should have produced: (top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5), and the second should have produced  (top: 2.5, left: 2.5, bottom: 2.5, right: 2.5)

Comment: Also it should be called in viewDidLayoutSubviews

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56459563/1522584

Answer (score 51):

Only following code will do the job for your requirement, You don't need to create `UIBezierPath` for shadow path.

```
// *** Set masks bounds to NO to display shadow visible ***
self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
// *** Set light gray color as shown in sample ***
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
// *** *** Use following to add Shadow top, left ***
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5.0f, -5.0f);

// *** Use following to add Shadow bottom, right ***
//self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);

// *** Use following to add Shadow top, left, bottom, right ***
// avatarImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
// avatarImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;

// *** Set shadowOpacity to full (1) ***
self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but follow your code I will have the shadow in top-left. But what I want is I want to have a shadow in top-right-bottom-left. Maybe I explain not very well. Many thank for your time. I don't downvote it :(

Comment: I'm sure that `self.avatarImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;` not work. It don't display the shadow, it have tested ;)

Comment: @ Dipen Panchasara,  I believe OP wants the shadow in top-right AND bottom-left corner.  Your solution only allows shadow to appear at one corner only.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh to display shadow on all four side you need to add `shadowRadius`. I have updated my answer for it.

Comment: @GuntisTreulands I have added solution for Top-left-bottom-right, top-left, and bottom-right.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara now it working. it is very smart solution for achieve a shadow for 4 side, but the disadvantages is that I can not increase the size of the shadow. And also, the color of the shadow should be `black`, current in your code it is `lightGray`. if the shadow color is `lightGray`, it really hard to see the shadow

Comment: @PhanVănLinh you are right about shadow size, you can't increase when you want to apply on 4 sides, for that you need to use `UIBezierPath` only. You can change color according to your need. Thanks for mentioning. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 5):

**Without using UIBezierPath, CGSize.zero is the key here**

```
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = false
yourView?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
yourView?.layer.shadowOffset =  CGSize.zero
yourView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
yourView?.layer.shadowRadius = 4
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Little less code for swift 3:

```
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: planView.bounds).cgPath
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for shadow with a rounded corner on the same view and no need to do clipsToBounds or maskToBounds

```
func addShadow(cornerRadius: CGFloat, maskedCorners: CACornerMask, color: UIColor, offset: CGSize, opacity: Float, shadowRadius: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.layer.maskedCorners = maskedCorners
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = offset
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For UIView and Adding shadow, remember to set background color to the UIView.

If the background color is clearColor, no shadow appears.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still not getting proper shadow, the problem might be the place you added the code.
You should call this in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** when you use UIBezierPath. If you call in ViewDidLoad, you may get wrong result since the views layout process might be unfinished.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    //Shadow code here
}
```

Comment: This solve my BezierPath problem..

Answer (score 1):

//If you’ve tried this before, you know exactly what happens. The corners will be rounded, but the shadow will be missing. If you set masksToBounds to false, the shadow will appear, but the corners will not be rounded.
//to get Shadow with corner radius 
Add super view for container view with clear color and apply shadow for super view ,Apply corner radius for container View. try it.

```
   //view to apply shadow and corner radius
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    containerView.clipsToBounds = true
    //superview of container View for to apply shadow 
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero

    shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.Black.cgColor

    shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:containerView.bounds, cornerRadius: containerView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    shadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Answer (score 0):

CGRectInset(self.avatarImageView.bounds, -10.0, -10.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
**in swift 4**

  yourView.clipsToBounds = true
    yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    yourView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.yourView.bounds,
                     cornerRadius: self.DeletConversation.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(hexString: "color")?.cgColor
    DeletConversation.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    DeletConversation.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
    DeletConversation.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    DeletConversation.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed explanation about this here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-shadow-to-a-uiview.

If someone is straggling with no top shadow in a collection view then this may help:

I know that this may be obvious for some people, but if you have a CollectionView with header and cell, make sure that you have space between the header and the cell, otherwise, the top shadow of the cell will be blocked by the header.

To add space, just use the insetsForSectionAt section.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 0)

}
```