# Tableview Xib Shadow Swift

Tags: ios, css, swift, uitableview

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

[image: Original Screen Shot]

**The screenshot is taken from Iphone:**

[image: Taken Screenshot]

**This is my code:**

```
cell.shadowLayerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.shadowLayerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
cell.shadowLayerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.shadowLayerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.23
cell.shadowLayerView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
cell.shadowLayerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.shadowLayerView.bounds, cornerRadius: 2).cgPath
cell.shadowLayerView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
cell.shadowLayerView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
cell.discriptionLbl.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
```

This is my tableview xib. In original image show light gray color shadow all side(Top,Bottom,left,Right) but in taken image show all side shadow but why show extra shadow in right side and bottom side.

**See Below Image:**

[image: Latest Taken Image]

**Question:** How to show same shadow from all side of the view like original image(shadow in light gray color)?

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this , i've tried to solve this issue but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [this link may help you to get what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645408/uitableviewcell-rounded-corners-and-shadow)

Comment: Supplying only a link as an answer is discouraged. The link can break if the page moves. Please consider explaining the basics of the answer you are providing since we’re not here to do basic searches that the OP could do themselves.

Comment: set the shadow for cell contentView

Comment: update question please check and give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code:

```
mainViewCorner.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor;
mainViewCorner.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero //direction of shadow
mainViewCorner.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0; // opacity for shadow
mainViewCorner.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0; //amount of shadow to blur
mainViewCorner.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
```

issue with your code was `shadowOffset`. It defines the direction of your shadow. If you want shadow on all sides - it must have zero value for both width and height.

Comment: @Sam : Have you read my answer, I already explained that, `shadowOffset` defines the direction for your shadow. So, if you want shadow equal in all directions, then `shadowOffset` must be CGSize.zero

Comment: In what you have tried - please remove `shadowPath`, As you are using shadowPath and shadowOffset both, it will get conflict

Comment: Ya @Mehul you are right you solve my problem thank you very much please explain when i m trying to CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0) and cgsize.zero is not same ?//

Comment: You can see answer of Dipen in this question(Dont forget to read comments in the code he provided, otherwise it will not work): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173052/ios-how-to-make-a-shadow-for-uiview-on-4-side-top-right-bottom-and-left,

Comment: yes both cgsize are same, user whichever looks better to you. both are same. @Sam

Comment: but when i m trying to set CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0) they show not properly but when i try to CGSize.zero then solved my problem ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186027/discussion-between-sam-and-mehul-thakkar).

Comment: This looks strange... @Sam, In my code, i always use the code that i pasted, not cgsize.zero and it is working in my case. Probably you missed something

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
   myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
   let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myView.bounds, cornerRadius: 10)

    myView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

Or you can use Sketch Shadow

```
extension CALayer {
    func applySketchShadow(
        color: UIColor = .black,
        alpha: Float = 0.5,
        x: CGFloat = 0,
        y: CGFloat = 2,
        blur: CGFloat = 4,
        spread: CGFloat = 0)
    {
        shadowColor = color.cgColor
        shadowOpacity = alpha
        shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
        shadowRadius = blur / 2.0
        if spread == 0 {
            shadowPath = nil
        } else {
            let dx = -spread
            let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
            shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
        }
    }
}
```

apply Sketch Shadow

```
 myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myView.bounds, cornerRadius: 10)

   myView.layer.applySketchShadow(
            color: .black, 
            alpha: 0.5, 
            x: CGFloat(0), 
            y: CGFloat(10), 
            blur: 20, 
            spread: 0)
        myView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
```